# Posix threaded program

Tags: c, pthreads

In a posix threaded(pthread) linux program base process and child thread executes code(some shared reentrant). To debug need to print identifier to know who is executing a line of code(base process or a thread). How does one do it ?

Comment: What programming language? Show us your code.

Comment: C-code with pthreads.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gettid()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettid):

> ```
> #include <sys/types.h>
> pid_t gettid(void);
> ```
>
> **gettid()** returns the caller's thread ID (TID). In a single-threaded process, the thread ID is equal to the process ID (PID, as returned by [***getpid(2)***](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid)). In a multithreaded process, all threads have the same PID, but each one has a unique TID.

Comment: [Is there a way to see details of all the threads that a process has in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux)